# Is there a word that describes a difference in hierarchy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes that there is a hierarchical difference between two objects that are of a different rank. For example, if object A is "School" and object B is "Student", then B is below A in the data hierarchy. Can this be described with a single word or short phrase?

> Sample Sentence: "Two entities are _______ in the hierarchy"

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right answer so I'll put it as a comment; "hyponymy, subordination - the semantic relation of being subordinate or belonging to a lower rank or class" (from The Free Dictionary by Farlex). These relations are called *semantic relations* and there are meronymy, holonymy etc. to maybe suit your needs.

Comment: Hyponymy seems to point to two objects that are of the same class or type, however in my case objects on the hierarchy can be of difference types. While I don't think it suits my needs it's very interesting, thanks for the reply! I think the literal definition of "subordinate" is more suited to my needs, however subordinate tends to point to an hierarchy of authority.

Comment: I looked further and found that "X" is a meronym of "Y" if Xs are members of Y(s). (from Wikipedia). I too think that subordinate feels too authoritative.

Comment: Very cool, I think meronym would work in my original example, depending on how you define a School. If you consider a School as all the working elements that make up the institution instead of just the building then I would say Student could be a meronym of School. However, if you consider Principal vs Student you wouldn't consider Student a meronym of Principal, since the student isn't physically a part of the principal. Salesman vs Customer is an interesting example, a Salesman can sell to many Customers, but the Customer would not be considered a meronym or a subordinate to the Salesman.

Comment: I'm also a bit unsure of what you are looking for. Something like 'the 2 entities are ranked/ordered differently in the hierarchy'? Or the 2 entities are at different stages/levels in the hierarchy? With your sample sentence I can't think of a phrase without the modifier (or a synonym of) 'different/ly'

Comment: They have a parent-child relationship.

Comment: The two entities are (directly) linked in the hierarchy. The only possible link in a dependency graph is from a superior to an inferior.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sentence already includes "hierarchy", any dissimilarity between entities would presume a difference in rank.  I would therefore think that *dissimilar*, *unequal*, *disparate*, or the like would work, without resorting to five-dollar words like *meronym* and *hyponymy*.  The phrase "of different rank", used in the original question  seems fine to me.